# How to use IBinder when binding to a service in another application

Tags: android, android-service

I've seen some examples on how to bind to a service within the same application, and see that in `ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected()` the `IBinder` is cast to the actual Binder class from the service.

My question is: What do I do next to actually make use of the IBinder passed into `ServiceConnection.onServiceConnected()` when binding from a different application?

(I think maybe my lack of java skills is what is hindering me from seeing some obvious solution here. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a RemoteInterface using AIDL.

See
[Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL)](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html)

I wouldn't say that you had missed anything *obvious*.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Anyone else seeing this question might want to know that there is a separate topic on Android Developers covering this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html